# Dual Booting Samsung ATIV 9

Tags: dual-boot

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 on my new Samsung ATIV 9 and I'm running into some problems with the BIOS. I've followed the guides saying to disable SecureBoot, select CSM (Compatibility Support Mode) option, and turn off Fastboot, but I'm still having some issues. I am trying to setup my BIOS to read from a USB first, but when I go to Boot Priorities, I only have the option to launch Windows or to Disable the boot. How can I add Boot from USB to this list?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. "USB" does not have to (and may never) appear on the boot menu. As far as I can remember you should disable the fast boot and secure boot options on the Boot page in BIOS. (I think they are the last two items on the list). You may have to choose "Disable" in the boot priority menu as well. Then try booting from USB.

Now something very important. You should choose UEFI not CMS. Look here: [Dual boot Ubuntu+Windows 8: Ubuntu won't show up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499687/dual-boot-ubuntuwindows-8-ubuntu-wont-show-up/499831#499831)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have taken BIOS update from Samsung. Setup your BIOS setting for boot to CSM only. Insert a bootable ubuntu usb stick and reboot. It should boot from usb now.