# Dual boot Ubuntu+Windows 8: Ubuntu won't show up

Tags: grub2, windows

Yes, there are many posts on this site related to this problem especially [Dual boot menu with Ubuntu and Windows 8 not showing up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327676/dual-boot-menu-with-ubuntu-and-windows-8-not-showing-up) and [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) . But I'm still unable solve the problem.

I disable fast boot and secure boot in Windows 8.1 and installed Xubuntu Trusty from a Live disk but no GRUB menu whatsoever. The peculiar part is that in the BIOS the "Boot Device Priority" has only two options: "Windows Boot Manager" and "Disabled". I think it's the "Disabled" thing that should be enables but unfortunately I don't know what it is exactly!

I ran Boot Repair from live disk twice with no benefit. The machine is a Samsung ATIV 9. I understand that this question is more about a particular machine's BIOS and Win 8 but I need the answer to be able to use Ubuntu.

Here is the lower part of the output of Boot Repair:

```
/boot/efi detected in the fstab of sda8: UUID=1C3F-D310     (sda2)

*******lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c109]
Kernel driver in use: i915
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 09)
*******

grub-install: info: executing modprobe efivars 2>/dev/null.
grub-install: info: Looking for /sys/firmware/efi ...
grub-install: info: ... not found. Looking for /proc/device-tree ...
grub-install: info: ... not found.
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
,.
GRUB too old for SecureBoot. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 efibootmgr -v
Fatal: Couldn't open either sysfs or procfs directories for accessing EFI variables.
Try 'modprobe efivars' as root.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 uname -r
Kernel: 3.13.0-24-generic

Reinstall the grub-efi of sda8
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
grub-install : exit code of grub-install :1
Error: no grub*.efi generated. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

Add /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/boot/efi efi entries in /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/etc/grub.d/25_custom
Adding custom /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding custom /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
sda2/bootx64.efi already added
sda2/bootmgfw.efi already added
Add /mnt/boot-sav/sda6 efi entries in /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/etc/grub.d/25_custom
Adding custom /mnt/boot-sav/sda6/EFI/Asclepius/bootx64.efi

---- Grub-install verbose
/usr/sbin/grub-install: 1: /usr/sbin/grub-install: cannot create nŵ?ŵ????T?T?@T?@DD?Påtd?ŒÒ?ŒÒLŒÒLl9l9?Qåtd??Råtd?ŵ=?ŵ=nŵ=n?????/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2???GNU??????GNUm: Directory nonexistent
+ ELF???? @????@@@@@ø?ø????8?8?@8?@?????@@d:?d:? ??ŵ=?ŵ=nŵ=nž{ ? ???
/usr/sbin/grub-install: 1: /usr/sbin/grub-install: ELF????: not found
/usr/sbin/grub-install: 2: /usr/sbin/grub-install: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
--------
/usr/sbin/grub-install : exit code of grub-install :2
---- End of grub-install verbose


chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 efibootmgr -v
Fatal: Couldn't open either sysfs or procfs directories for accessing EFI variables.
Try 'modprobe efivars' as root.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda2
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda8/boot/grub/grub.cfg

An error occurred during the repair.

You can now reboot your computer.


You may want to retry after deactivating the [Backup and rename Windows EFI files] option.

The boot of your PC is in Legacy mode. You may want to retry after changing it to EFI mode.
```

Comment: Enable EFI boot and try again. Select Ubuntu from your bios options.

Comment: have you tried going into the bios and enabling uefi mode? Also, if the bios is "stuck" in legacy bios mode, you might try using the mac version of the install media to make it install in that mode by default

Comment: IN BIOS there are 3 options: CMS, UEFI, UEFI & CMS. But no matter which one I choose, there is no boot option for Ubuntu. There is only the "Disabled" option which I don't know what it is actually.

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this guide](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/). The point is I had to choose the boot option UEFI after disabling secure boot, and then install Ubuntu. Previously I had set it to CMS.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.